# Error when CUploadedFile assign image property using extension mongodbsuite in Yii framework

Tags: php, mongodb, yii-extensions, yii

I'm using mongodb suite in yii framework, when assign CUploadedFile to public property image class model , get error :

```
MongoException

zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?

/var/www/html/bablog/protected/extensions/YiiMongoDbSuite/EMongoDocument.php(611)
```

[image: Error Pic]

model class :

```
...
public function rules() {

        return array(
           ...
            array('image', 'file',
              'types'=>'jpg,jpeg, png' ,
              'mimeTypes' => 'image/jpeg , image/pjpeg,image/png' ,
              'safe'=>true,
              'maxFiles' => 1 ,
              'maxSize' => 1024 ,
              'minSize' => 100 ,
              ),
        );
}
```

add code :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image'));
die();
```

output:

```
CUploadedFile Object
(
    [_name:CUploadedFile:private] => download.jpg
    [_tempName:CUploadedFile:private] => /tmp/phpC8GRRt
    [_type:CUploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
    [_size:CUploadedFile:private] => 530
    [_error:CUploadedFile:private] => 0
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

try :

1- declare image dynamic property in model , but define __set function in parent again get same error.

2- define protected property but CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image') requirement public property , As a result, get error :( :D .

Question :

1-For the above problem, what do I do?

2- Is there any way that we define our own attributes in mongodbsuite , Instead of get attributes public property in class?

Sorry for my poor English

tnx for All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i'm multiple upload files :

view file :

```
.....
    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image[0]'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image[0]'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'image[0]'); ?>
        </div>

                        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image[1]'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image[1]'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'image[1]'); ?>
        </div>
.....
```

controller file:

```
<?php

    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new Post;
        $images = array();
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if (isset($_POST['Post'])) {
            $countImage = count($_POST['Post']['image']);
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Post'];
            $model->status = $_POST['Status'];

            $j = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $countImage; $i++) {

                $imageTemp = new Post;
                $imageTemp->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($imageTemp, "image[$i]");

                if (!empty($imageTemp->image)) {
                    $images[$j] = $imageTemp;
                    $j++;
                }
                unset($imageTemp);
            }

            if ($model->save()) {

                foreach ($images as $i => $image) {

                    $namePic[$i] = Yii::app()->params['pathImages'] . Yii::app()->params['domainName'] . '-' . (string) $model->_id . '-' . time() . '-' . rand(1, 1000) . '.' . $image->image->getExtensionName();
                    $image->image->saveAs($namePic[$i]);
                }

                $model->image = $namePic;
                $model->update(array('image'), true);
                unset($images);

//$this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->_id));
            }
        }

        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

model :

```
public function rules() {

        return array(....
            array('image', 'file',
              'types'=>'jpg, png' ,
              'mimeTypes' => 'image/gif, image/jpeg' ,
              'safe'=>true,
              'maxFiles' => 3 ,
              'maxSize' => 10240000 ,
              ),
....
        );
    }
```

finish :D

I hope it's been getting better